# Failed to load an image in my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: image, url, elementor

I made an Elementor plugin which contains an image.
The image works fine on my local machine, but it isn't shown after installing the plugin on a live site.
I think there is a problem on the url of the image. But I have no idea how to fix it.

This is the code snippet I'm using in the index.php.

`<img src="<?php echo plugins_url('/custom-calculator/images/mailbox.png') ?>" alt="mailbox" />`

And this is the file structure of the plugin.

```
/custom-calculator
  index.php
  script.js
  styles.css
  /images
    mailbox.png
```

I need your help.
Thank you.